# PHP FTP file upload does not work

Tags: php, upload, ftp

I have pretty strange problem. A web application moved from one server to another one. Since then the FTP upload is not working anymore.

```
$ftp = ftp_connect('ftphost');
if ($ftp == false) {
    error_log('FTP Connect not possible');
}
$fp = fopen($filename, 'r');
if ($fp == false) {
    error_log('Opening file not possible');
}
$login = ftp_login($ftp, 'username', 'password');

if ($login == false) {
    error_log('FTP login not possible');
}

$status = ftp_fput($ftp, basename($filename), $fp, FTP_BINARY);
if ($status == false) {
    error_log('FTP file upload not possible');
}
```

The error message is 'FTP file upload not possible'. I checked everything I know of. Selinux is disabled. When I do a FTP upload by hand (on the console with the tool "ftp") it works. The file names are randomly generated and always look like this: erefsdgftef.xml (No spaces.)

This code is part of the last order step within Magento and will therefore always be initiated through the apache httpd.

I don't get more error messages than the one posted before.

Something with the server configuration must be different on the new server. Does someone have more ideas?

Comment: Shouldn't this be on serverfault?

Comment: what about ftp_pasv ? maybe the ftp doesn't support active connection? (I dunno)

Comment: If you can manually login to the same FTP server with the same username+password - it sounds like a code issue. Since you can connect to the server, DNS or routing doesn't seem to be an issue. You could check that basename($filename) looks as expected

Comment: I would also check the errors logs and make sure the ftp got permissions to write files to your location on the server side.

Comment: @MiPnamic: As I wrote. I tried it on the console and it worked with an active connection. And it works on the old server too.

Comment: @Rolando Cruz: Yes, it could be on serverfault too. You can vote to move it. For me it could belong on both sites.

Comment: @Dan J: On the old server it is working properly. So I don't think it is a code issue. Basename() looks as expected.

Comment: @Ido Green: FTP has the permission to write files. As I write if I test it by hand with the console program "ftp" it works without problems.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure this is your answer but did you already tried to do it in passive mode?

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ftp-pasv.php

Comment: MiPnamic was a little earlier then me

Comment: As I wrote. I tried it on the console and it worked with an active connection. And it works on the old server too.